# Label intersection points of several curves

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to label all intersection points between 2 functions and a 3rd one in a Plot by using [Kuba's second solution from here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32081/labeling-points-of-intersection-between-plots/32083?noredirect=1#comment254825_32083) , but I'm not getting the expected result: there are additional, wrong intersection points and the label letters are not correct positioned. What I'm doing wrong?

```
opts = {ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 5}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 84, MaxRecursion -> 9,
   MeshFunctions -> {f1[#1] - f3[#1] &, f2[#1] - f3[#1] &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]}};
points = Join[{x, f1[x]} /. 
   NSolve[f1[x] == f3[x] && -3 < x < 3, x, Reals], {x, f2[x]} /. 
   NSolve[f2[x] == f3[x] && -3 < x < 3, x, Reals]];
names = FromCharacterCode /@ (Range[Length@points] + 
   96); 
Row[{Plot[{f1[p], f2[p], f3[p]}, {p, -3, 3}, Evaluate@opts, 
   Epilog -> (Text[Style[#, 15], #2 + {.5, 0}] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{names, points}])], 
  Grid@MapThread[List, {names, points}]}]
```

What I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generalizing to a variable number of functions

```
n = 3; (* number of functions *)

f[1][x_] := 1/2 x;
f[2][x_] := Cos[5 x];
f[3][x_] := x^2 - 2;

points =
  SortBy[
   Flatten[
    ({x, #[[1]]} /.
        NSolve[#, x, Reals]) & /@
     (Equal @@@ 
       Subsets[f[#][x] & /@ Range[n], {2}])
    , 1]
   , First];

opts = {
   Frame -> True
   , FrameLabel ->
    ((Style[#, Blue, 15, Bold] // TraditionalForm) & /@
      {x, 
       f[x]})
   , Axes -> False
   , ImageSize -> 432
   , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 2}}
   , PlotLegends ->
    Placed[f[#][x] & /@ Range[n], Above]};

names = FromCharacterCode /@ (Range[
      Length@points] + ToCharacterCode["a"][[1]] - 1);

Column[{
  Plot[
   Evaluate[f[#][x] & /@ Range[n]]
   , {x, -3, 3},
   Evaluate@opts
   , Epilog -> ({Black
        , Text[Style[#, 15, Bold], #2, {-1, -1}]
        , Red
        , AbsolutePointSize[4]
        , Point[#2]} & @@@
      Transpose[{names, points}])]
  , Grid[
   Prepend[
    Flatten /@ Transpose@{names, points},
    {"Label", "x", "y"}]
   , Frame -> All]}
 , Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Well, the answer of cuba is not directly applicable for 3 functions. That is the reason. When you want to draw points, why don't you do it directly in `Epilog` where you create the positions of the labels anyway. No need to give you a hard time with `Mesh`:

```
f1[x_] := 1/2 x;
f2[x_] := Cos[5 x];
f3[x_] := x^2 - 2;

opts = {ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 5}}};

names = FromCharacterCode /@ (Range[Length@points] + 96);
Plot[{f1[p], f2[p], f3[p]}, {p, -3, 3}, Evaluate@opts, 
 Epilog -> ({Black, Text[Style[#, 15], #2 + {0.05, 0.2}], Red, 
      Point[#2]} & @@@ Transpose[{names, points}])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: harlirutan gave you the primary answer where you need to add `{x, f1[x]} /. NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x] && -3 < x < 3, x, Reals]` to your computation of `points` and then remove the complex `Mesh` from the graphics. Epilog works fine. Another approach is to use `Show` to join graphics. `Show[
 Plot[{f1[p], f2[p], f3[p]}, {p, -3, 3}, Evaluate@opts],
 ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}],
 Graphics[
  Text[Style[#, 15], #2 + {.5, 0}] & @@@ Transpose[{names, points}]
  ]
 ]`

Comment: @JackLaVigne Just post your comment as separate answer. Everyone would welcome some diversity!