# Marking Specific Points on Graph

Tags: plotting

Is there any way that I can label/mark points (axes intercepts, maximum/minimum values etc.) on *Mathematica*? (as in without using the drawing tools)

Such as in the case of: `Plot[{x^3 - 6*x^2 + 9*x + 10}, {x, 0, 4}]`

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Epilog`  to add whatever you want, but you have to calculate those point's positions. Related: [Labeling points of intersection between plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32081/5478)

Comment: Hi @Kuba Thanks for your response - I'm new to mathematica, and although this might sound a bit amateurish/childish - Can you please show me what the coding may look like in a basic graph? Such as in the aforementioned example or something of the like.

Comment: Type in `Epilog` to Mathematica notebook, press F1 :)

Comment: Alright, I think I get it now - Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Sven, the point is the the documentation of [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) does contain the examples you are after, so the pointer provided by Kuba is actually enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of some of the things you could do using `Epilog`, which essentially allows you to combine any 2D graphics primitives on top of an existing plot.

I will define your function as `fun[x]`:

```
Clear[fun, realzero]
fun[x_] := x^3 - 6*x^2 + 9*x + 10
```

I can use `Solve` to find the function's zeroes, i.e. its intersections with the horizontal axis:

```
realzero = {x, 0} /. First@Solve[fun[x] == 0., x, Reals]

(* Out: {-0.721892, 0} *)
```

I then have `Mathematica` calculate the expression's first derivative and set up an equation to find its zeroes, i.e. the function's extrema.

```
Solve[D[fun[x], x] == 0, x]

(* Out: {{x -> 1}, {x -> 3}} *)
```

I can then combine what I found in a plot:

```
Plot[fun[x], {x, -1, 4},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.03],
   Red, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[{1, fun[1]}],
   Blue, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[{3, fun[3]}],
   Darker@Green, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[realzero],
   Orange, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[{0, fun[0]}]
   },
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, All}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {None, {0, Scaled[0.1]}},
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {"x", "y"})
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you execute the code in `Mathematica` and hover over those points with the mouse, you will also notice that a tooltip pops up with the coordinates for those points.

I would suggest that you use this code as a starting point to explore the commands and options showcased: play around with it, modify it, dig into the documentation... *Mathematica* can be a lot of fun!

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is a great starting point - Can't wait to discover more!! :D