# Locate intersection points in a contour plot

Tags: plotting, intersection

I have the following output from `ContourPlot`, and I would like to be able to find what the intersection points of the two curves are, without using any other information on the functions plotted, other than what is seen in the picture.

[image]

The image was produced using the following code:

```
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
Θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];

f[x_, y_, t_] := 
 1/2 - BesselK[0, r[x, y]]/(
  2 BesselK[0, 1]) + ϵ1[t] BesselK[0, r[x, y]]/
   BesselK[0, 1] + 
  D1[t] BesselK[1, r[x, y]]/(2 BesselK[1, 1])Cos[Θ[x, y] + ζ1[t]]

g[x_, y_, t_] := 
 Sin[Θ[x, y] + ζ2[t]]/
  r[x, y] + ϵ2/2 r[x, y]^(-1/2) Cos[Θ[x, y]/2]

ϵ1[t_] = -0.5 + 10^-6 t;
ζ2[t_] = π/3 + 10^-4 t;
ζ1[t_] = π/3 + 10^-6 t;
ϵ2 = 0.5;
D1[t_] = 0.5 - 10^-3 t;

 ContourPlot[{g[x, y, 0] == 0, f[x, y, 0] == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/12

Comment: Can be any output produced by ContourPlot and exported through Mma. I guess this would more easily be an image file?

Comment: @Kuba In the case of interest this would be Graphics output then, sorry.

Comment: Sure, here it is - edited the question!

Comment: related: [Labeling points of intersection between plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32081/5478)

Comment: Now it should work with only one circle

Answer (score 6):

If `plot` is defined as your `ContourPlot`, then you can get the intersection points by extracting the `Line` objects from the plot and using [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html)

```
plot // Normal // Cases[#, Line[_], Infinity] & // Apply@RegionIntersection

(* Point[{{-1.02539, 1.31753}, {0.379181, -1.26021}}] *)
```

and verify the results

```
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, %}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Version 11

For some reason version 11 will produce a disconnected line for the first contour, and so when you extract the lines you have more than 2, and there is no point where they all intersect and so the result is an [`EmptyRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmptyRegion.html).  A workaround is to find the points where any two lines intersect.

```
plot // Normal // Cases[#, Line[_], Infinity] & // Subsets[#, {2}] & //
   Map@Apply@RegionIntersection // DeleteCases[_EmptyRegion]
(* {Point[{{0.379181, -1.26021}}], Point[{{-1.031, 1.31378}}]} *)
```

Comment: `EmptyRegion[2]` from 11.0.0, OP's code as copied gives a gap in a blue line that is why the result is empty.

Comment: Looks like `ContourPlot` produces a single line for `g[x, y, 0] == 0` in version 10, but in version 11 it's two unconnected lines.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so all we have is

```
plot = ContourPlot[{g[x, y, 0] == 0, f[x, y, 0] == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to view all of the information we have about the curves we can use `FullForm[plot]`. We see that we have all of the points that make up the lines, and that they are wrapped by `Line`. We can extract the points like this:

```
lines = Cases[Normal[plot], _Line, Infinity];
{pts1, pts2} = lines /. Line -> Identity;
```

We now have the points corresponding to each of the lines. In order to find the intersection between the lines it would be suitable to linearly interpolate between the points. In order to interpolate with `Interpolation` we need to introduce an independent variable, and I will introduce the distance along the curve as that independent variable.

```
createInterpolation[pts_] := Interpolation[Transpose[{
    Prepend[0]@Accumulate@Map[Norm, Differences@pts],
    pts
    }], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
curve1 = createInterpolation[pts1];
curve2 = createInterpolation[pts2];
```

We can plot the interpolated functions to see that we got it right:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[curve1[d], {d, 0, 23.9}],
 ParametricPlot[curve2[d], {d, 0, 9.48}, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2]],
 PlotRange -> 10, Axes -> False, Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now that we have functions that are continuous over the relevant domain, we can use `NMinimize` to find the intersections.

```
sol1 = Last@NMinimize[{
    Norm[curve1[d1] - curve2[d2]]^2,
    0 < d1 < 23.9 && 0 < d2 < 9.49
    }, {d1, d2}]
```

> `{d1 -> 12.2012, d2 -> 4.63393}`

To find the other intersection we can change the constraints to exclude the intersection that has already been found:

```
sol2 = Last@NMinimize[{
    Norm[curve1[d1] - curve2[d2]]^2,
    0 < d1 < 10 && 0 < d2 < 9.48
    }, {d1, d2}]
```

> `{d1 -> 8.97608, d2 -> 9.48}`

Finally we can plot the solutions to gauge whether they are correct:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[curve1[d], {d, 0, 23.9}],
 ParametricPlot[curve2[d], {d, 0, 9.48}, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2]],
 PlotRange -> 10, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{curve1[d1] /. sol1, curve1[d1] /. sol2}]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If you need precision results I'd use this:

```
FindMinimum[f[x, y, 0]^2 + g[x, y, 0]^2, {{x, -1}, {y, 1}}]
FindMinimum[f[x, y, 0]^2 + g[x, y, 0]^2, {{x, 0}, {y, -1}}]
```

where the initial guesses are taken from the contour plot.

> {3.51393*10^-25, {x -> -1.02897, y -> 1.31148}}
>
> {5.69013*10^-19, {x -> 0.378089, y -> -1.26037}}

Comment: "..., without using any other information on the functions plotted, other than what is seen in the picture."

Comment: @kuba, fair enough, but someone else might encounter the question and not have that restriction.  The results taken from the plot are off by ~0.005, which is obviously good enough if you just want to put a marker on the plot.