# Finding where two parametric paths cross?

Tags: equation-solving

I have been looking through other parametric equations questions and am still unsure where to start with this one. I am given two functions:

```
f[t_] = {16.2 - 7 t + t^2, 13 t - 2 t^2};
g[t_] = {26 - 13.1 t + 2 t^2, 23 - 6 t + t^2};
```

How do I show where these two parametric paths cross? How would I simplify these two sets? Thank you!

Comment: Related: [(275)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/121),
[(10472)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10472/121),
[(11364)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11364/121),
[(18564)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18564/121),
[(24875)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24875/121),
[(28987)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28987/121),
[(32081)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32081/121),
[(35107)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35107/121),
[(42304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42304/121),
 continued...

Comment: Related: [(51115)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51115/121),
[(65895)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65895/121),
[(69980)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69980/121),
[(86805)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86805/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If they don't need to cross at the same $t$, then you can solve

```
Solve[f[t1] == g[t2], {t1, t2}]
```

since they are polynomials. Otherwise, you might use `FindRoot`. This yields a set of four solutions. You can then plug these pairs of `t1` and `t2` back into your expressions for `f` and `g` to get the actual points where the curves cross.

Answer (score 7):

```
f[t_] := {16.2 - 7 t + t^2, 13 t - 2 t^2};
g[t_] := {26 - 13.1 t + 2 t^2, 23 - 6 t + t^2};

sols = Transpose[{t, t1} /. NSolve[f@t == g@t1, {t, t1}]]
p[f_, c_] := ParametricPlot[f[t], Evaluate@{t, Sequence @@ ({Max@#, Min@#} &@sols)}, 
                            PlotRange -> All,  PlotStyle -> c]

Show[p[f, Red], p[g, Green], Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[f /@ sols[[1]]]}], 
     AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Attacking the problem from a different point of view:

```
f[t_] = {16.2 - 7 t + t^2, 13 t - 2 t^2};
g[t_] = {26 - 13.1 t + 2 t^2, 23 - 6 t + t^2};

pts = NSolve[Thread[f[t1] == g[t2]], {t1, t2}]
```

> ```
> {{t1 -> 5.07271, t2 -> 2.30684}, {t1 -> 4.95465, t2 -> 4.146}, 
>  {t1 -> 1.66574, t2 -> 4.45096}, {t1 -> 1.50689, t2 -> 1.97621}}
> ```

```
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate@Thread[f[t1] == g[t2]], {t1, 0, 6}, {t2, 0, 6}, 
      FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{t1, t2} /. pts]}]]
```

> [image: Solution]

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking just to show them then you can also use `RegionIntersection`

```
r1 = ParametricRegion[f[t], {{t, 1, 6}}];
r2 = ParametricRegion[g[t], {{t, 1, 6}}];
int = RegionIntersection[r1, r2];

RegionPlot[{r1, r2, int}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {3, 25}, BoundaryStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just post as another method.

Considering the two parametric equations are polynomials，we can obtain the implicit equation by eliminate the parametric $t$.

Using the function `GroebnerBasis`.

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Evaluate@GroebnerBasis[{x - (162/10 - 7 t + t^2), 
    y - (13 t - 2 t^2)}, {t, x, y}][[1]];
g[x_, y_] := 
  Evaluate@GroebnerBasis[{x - (26 - 131/10 t + 2 t^2), 
    y - (23 - 6 t + t^2)}, {t, x, y}][[1]]
```

Then plot the two curves and their cross points.

```
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 3, 10}, {y, 12, 22}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Mesh -> {{0, 0}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] &, g[#1, #2] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is as good an excuse as any to use Gröbner bases.:) But, why not do `GroebnerBasis[(* equations *), {x, y}, t]`? That should explicitly eliminate the parameter.

Comment: @J. M. Hasn't this kind of question been asked before?  Can you find a good duplicate to close this toward?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I knew from the moment I saw this question, but I'm still having trouble with which question should it be a dupe of.

Comment: @J. M. I added my customary **Related** links below the Question.  Please consider reviewing these and closing and retagging as appropriate.  (For example I notice `intersection` is being used in a possibly inconsistent way.)  I think we are in need of a canonical Q&A for this topic that outlines common categories of problems and solutions within this domain.  Would you be willing to undertake this project?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, as you know, the business of solving equations is hard. ;) But, if I can get computer access in the coming weekend, I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: @J. M. That would be great.  Obviously I don't expect *A Solution to Everything* but rather addressing the cases and methods that come up repeatedly, and you are far more capable of that goal than I am.  Thank you.